# How to Change the Width of Bars in Bar Diagram

Tags: asp.net, telerik

this is my code:-

```
<telerik:RadChart  OnClick="radChart1_Click" PlotArea-Appearance-FillStyle-MainColor="Transparent" 
     PlotArea-Appearance-FillStyle-SecondColor="Transparent"   ID="RadChart1" 
     runat="server" IntelligentLabelsEnabled="True" PlotArea-Visible="True" 
     Skin="Office2007" style="margin-left: 0px"  AutoLayout="true" Height="400px" Width="680px" >                 
                              <Appearance>
                                  <Border Color="134, 134, 134" />
                              </Appearance>
                              <Series>
                                  <telerik:ChartSeries Name="Series 1">
                                      <Appearance>
                                          <FillStyle FillType="Solid" MainColor="69, 115, 167">
                                          </FillStyle>
                                          <TextAppearance TextProperties-Color="Black">
                                          </TextAppearance>
                                          <Border Color="69, 115, 167" />
                                      </Appearance>
                                  </telerik:ChartSeries>
                                  <telerik:ChartSeries Name="Series 2">
                                      <Appearance>
                                          <FillStyle FillType="Solid" MainColor="107, 70, 68">
                                          </FillStyle>
                                          <TextAppearance TextProperties-Color="Black">
                                          </TextAppearance>
                                          <Border Color="107, 70, 68" />
                                      </Appearance>
                                  </telerik:ChartSeries>
                              </Series>
                              <Legend>
                                  <Appearance Dimensions-Margins="15%, 2%, 1px, 1px" 
                                      Dimensions-Paddings="2px, 8px, 6px, 3px">
                                      <ItemTextAppearance TextProperties-Color="Black">
                                      </ItemTextAppearance>
                                      <ItemMarkerAppearance Figure="Square">
                                      </ItemMarkerAppearance>
                                  </Appearance>
                              </Legend>
                              <PlotArea>
                                  <XAxis>
                                      <Appearance Color="134, 134, 134" MajorTick-Color="134, 134, 134">
                                          <MajorGridLines Color="134, 134, 134" Width="0" />
                                          <TextAppearance TextProperties-Color="Black">
                                          </TextAppearance>
                                      </Appearance>
                                      <AxisLabel>
                                          <TextBlock>
                                              <Appearance TextProperties-Color="Black">
                                              </Appearance>
                                          </TextBlock>
                                      </AxisLabel>
                                  </XAxis>
                                  <YAxis>
                                      <Appearance Color="134, 134, 134" MajorTick-Color="134, 134, 134" 
                                          MinorTick-Color="134, 134, 134">
                                          <MajorGridLines Color="134, 134, 134" />
                                          <MinorGridLines Color="134, 134, 134" />
                                          <TextAppearance TextProperties-Color="Black">
                                          </TextAppearance>
                                      </Appearance>
                                      <AxisLabel>
                                          <TextBlock>
                                              <Appearance TextProperties-Color="Black">
                                              </Appearance>
                                          </TextBlock>
                                      </AxisLabel>
                                  </YAxis>
                                  <Appearance>
                                      <FillStyle MainColor="Transparent" SecondColor="Transparent">
                                      </FillStyle>
                                  </Appearance>
                              </PlotArea>
                              <ChartTitle>
                                  <Appearance>
                                      <FillStyle MainColor="">
                                      </FillStyle>
                                  </Appearance>
                                  <TextBlock Text="Ratio">
                                      <Appearance TextProperties-Color="Black" TextProperties-Font="Arial, 18px">
                                      </Appearance>
                                  </TextBlock>
                              </ChartTitle>

                        </telerik:RadChart> 
                     </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: I solved my problem i just add 1 line and my work was done. RadChart1.Appearance.BarWidthPercent = 50;  thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow! You should post this as an answer to the question and then accept the best answer (even if that is your own.)

Answer (score 0):

this code works in c#:
    `chartname.Appearance.BarWidthPercent = 30;`